# Issue with useEffect in child component rendering several times based on parent setting states in its own useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a parent component, with an `useEffect` that makes an api call, receives some data and then sets several hook states and a redux state. That triggers various re-renders of the component holding this `useEffect`, but this component has child components using useEffect, and the useEffect of the childs also trigger several times. How Could I workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to limit the triggering of the useEffect inside the child component what you can do is giving some dependencies to the hook of the child component:

```
useEffect(() => {
 // logic 
}, [props.test, otherProp, ...]);
```

By doing this the useEffect gets triggered only if the dependencies in the array changed. Also if you put as dependency an empty array than the useEffect will get triggered only once after the component gets mounted.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: The problem is, even if I put that, it's the parent component that is rendering, hence, it re-renders the child, and if the child is forced to re-render so it is the useEffect, right?

Comment: The child gets re-rendered, however the useEffect does not get triggered if the dependencies are not changed. If you want the child component to not re-render at all then you can wrap the child component inside a React.memo(). By doing this the parent component will make the child component re-render only if it changes one of the props.
Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Thank you. The child would only re-render if one of the props is changed or if internal states/redux changes, right?

Comment: Exactly. Please upvote the answer if I helped you